# Monty Hall Simulation

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-2.x

I wrote this code as my first self-directed effort and would appreciate any input on things that I've done seriously wrong. I worry that perhaps I'm over-relying on `if`-statements, for example, but am not sure how to change the pieces of code to use them less.

```
import random 

def playchosengame(chosengame):
    if chosengame == 1:
        doorchoice = int(raw_input("How many doors would you like to play with? > "))
        onegameatatime(doorchoice)
    elif chosengame == 2:
        numberofgames = int(raw_input("How many games would you like to play? > "))
        strategy = int(raw_input("Would you like to always change your answer (1) or keep it the same (2)? > "))
        doorchoice = int(raw_input("How many doors would you like to play with? > "))
        onestrategy(numberofgames,strategy,doorchoice)
    else:
        print "What did you say?"


def onestrategy(chosennumberofgames,chosenstrategy,doorchoice):
    # for playing x number of Monty Hall games with one type of strategy
    wincount = 0
    i = 1

    for i in range(1,chosennumberofgames + 1):
        possibleanswers = range(1,doorchoice + 1)
        correctanswer = random.randint(1,doorchoice)
        incorrectpossibilities = possibleanswers
        incorrectpossibilities.remove(correctanswer)

        youranswer = random.randint(1,doorchoice)

        if youranswer == correctanswer:
            otherremaining = random.choice(incorrectpossibilities)
        else:
            otherremaining = youranswer

        incorrectpossibilities.remove(otherremaining)

        print "The correct answer is NOT one of these: %r" % incorrectpossibilities

        if youranswer == correctanswer:
            print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (correctanswer, otherremaining)
            if chosenstrategy == 1:
                finalanswer = otherremaining
            else:
                finalanswer = correctanswer
        else:
            print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (youranswer, correctanswer)
            if chosenstrategy == 1:
                finalanswer = correctanswer
            else:
                finalanswer = youranswer

        print "You chose %r" % finalanswer

        if finalanswer == correctanswer:
            wincount += 1
            print "You win!"
        else:
            print "You lose!"

        i += 1

    print "You won %r out of %r games. Congrats!" % (wincount, i - 1)

def onegameatatime(doorchoice):
    # for playing one Monty Hall game at a time.
    playagain = 1

    while playagain == 1:
        possibleanswers = range(1,doorchoice + 1)
        correctanswer = random.randint(1,doorchoice)
        incorrectpossibilities = possibleanswers
        incorrectpossibilities.remove(correctanswer)

        youranswer = int(raw_input("Pick a door number from 1 - %r > " % doorchoice))

        if youranswer == correctanswer:
            otherremaining = random.choice(incorrectpossibilities)
        else:
            otherremaining = youranswer

        incorrectpossibilities.remove(otherremaining)

        print "The correct answer is NOT one of these: %r" % incorrectpossibilities

        if youranswer == correctanswer:
            print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (correctanswer, otherremaining)
        else:
            print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (youranswer, correctanswer)

        finalanswer = int(raw_input("Which do you choose? > "))

        if finalanswer == correctanswer:
            print "You win!"
        else:
            print "You lose!"

        playagain = int(raw_input("Play again? (1 = yes, 0 = no) > "))

    print "Thanks for playing!"

gamechoice = int(raw_input("Play one game at a time (1) or play your chosen number of games with one strategy (2)? > "))
playchosengame(gamechoice)
```

Comment: Youknowitsprettyhardtoreadlotsofwordswithoutsomedelimiter. Maybethatsworththinkingabout. Underscores_are_the_standard_IIRC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review and coding in general:

- *Code according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)* – In your case this means using `snake_case` for variable and function names, add spaces after commas and between operators. Your code does look rather nice in general, some minor nitpicks here and there, but read through the guidelines and try to adhere to them.
- ***Feature:** `incorrect_possibilities = possible_answers` invalidates `possible_answers`* – When you later on do `incorrect_possiblities.remove(correct_answer)` this also changes `possible_answers`. To get a copy you need either to use a better variant of [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), or simply `incorrect_possibilities = possible_answers[:]`. The latter one uses slicing to denote the entire array, and makes a copy of the sliced area.
- *Use ternary related to `chosen_strategy`* - Based on the chosen strategy you choose either of two choices, this can be coded as `final_answer = correct_answer if chosen_strategy == 1 else your_answer`, and similar in the other cases.
- *Use ternary related to print output also* – This can also be used in print out as well:

  ```
  print("Which means it is either your answer: {}, or the only other remaining option, {}.".format(
        correct_answer if your_answer == correct_answer else  your_answer,
        other_remaining if your_answer == correct_answer else correct_answer))
  ```
- *Use the newer `print('You chose {}'.format(final_answer)` syntax* – This is the preferred version for new code in Python 2 and for code in Python 3. See [Format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for examples and specification.
- *Use docstrings, `""" ... """`, and not comments, `# ...`, when describing modules, functions, classes and methods.* – If you use docstrings they can be used by your IDE or documentation tools, and it is according to the Pythonic way. :-)
- *Avoid one-time temporary variables* – The `playagain` can be dropped if you use `while True:` to keep the game going, and change the end to something like `if int(raw_input("Play again (0 = no)?")) == 0: break`. (Preferrably with a newline before the `break`, which does break out of the while loop)
- *Possibly add a loop or validation on the main loop* – If you enter something when choosing between playing one game at a time, or play a chosen number of games, you can enter something wrong and the script terminates. This could possibly be enhanced by adding a while loop around it.

  Do also note that if you enter non-numeric text your code breaks very easily...  Look into making a general int input function which uses `try ... except` around the `input` function.
- *Introducing the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom* – The previous code is often used to make the code reusable as a module, and to have as little code as possible at the top level. Combined with a `main()` function your code easily be reused and extended.

  In your case you could use (possibly extended with the while loop):

  ```
  def main(): 
      game_choice = int(raw_input("Play one game at a time (1) or play your chosen number of games with one strategy (2)? > "))
      play_chosen_game(game_choice)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      break
  ```
- *Consider shortening the text length* – Your texts are rather worthy, and could benefit from being shortened a little.

## Conclusion

Your code does look good for a beginner, and naming is good (with the exception of not using underscores in between words). You could benefit from learning to use the ternary operator (`a if b else c`), and a slight justification on using functions related to top level code and text lengths.

Answer (score 10):

**Read the <s>Bible</s>Style Guide**

Check out [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the style guide for Python. The thing that quickly jumps out at me from your code is how many of your variables and functions are `lotsofwordsstucktogetherwithoutanyspacing`. Those are very difficult to read. The preferred Python syntax is `snake_case`. That is:

```
def play_chosen_game(game_choice):
    ...
```

Much easier to parse.

**Python isn't like C/Java**

You don't have to predeclare variables, and you don't need to manually increment. Your main loop in `one_strategy` is:

```
i = 1
for i in range(1, num_games + 1):
    ...
    i += 1
```

This is wrong for several reasons: (1) you don't need the initial `i = 1` (2) The ending `i += 1` is meaningless (3) `range()` is the wrong construct (4) you reference `i` at the end of the loop when you really want `num_games`. Prefer the following:

```
for _ in xrange(num_games):
    ...
```

The `_` naming makes it clear that the variable isn't important - you're just doing something `num_games` times. Also, it doesn't matter if we iterate over `1..9` or `0..8`, so pick the one that's easier to spell.

Building on this, all we want is to count the number of wins, so let's make that explicit:

```
wins = 0
for _ in xrange(num_games):
    wins += play_game(num_doors, strategy_choice)
```

Moving all the logic you had in the loop into its own function.

**Picking a door**

The logic for picking a door is a little hard to follow. Let's simplify it. We start with all of our doors:

```
doors = range(num_doors)
```

We randomly pick one that's correct, and we randomly pick one for our choice:

```
answer = random.randint(0, num_doors - 1)
first_choice = random.randint(0, num_doors - 1)
```

Next, *based on the strategy*, we either stay or pick a different door:

```
if strategy_choice == 1:
    # pick a new door that isn't first_choice or some random wrong one
    goat = random.choice(
        [i for i in xrange(num_doors) if i not in (first_choice, answer)]
        )
    final_answer = random.choice(
        [i for i in xrange(num_doors) if i not in (first_choice, goat)]
        )
else:
    # stay put
    final_choice = first_choice
```

Much more direct.

Answer (score 7):

For your second week of coding, this is good work!

I would recommend reading over [Python's official style guide, PEP8](http://pep8online.com/).

I would also recommend reading some of our highest rated tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) questions for inspiration into how to improve / things to make.

---

### Space after commas:

In a few instances you're missing space after commas:

> ```
> for i in range(1,chosennumberofgames + 1):
> ```

PEP8 advises to provide a space after commas.

---

### `snake_case`:

You should be naming your variables in `snake_case`, which is what PEP8 also advises.

> ```
> incorrectpossibilities = possibleanswers
> ```

---

### Duplicate logic:

I'm seeing a lot of duplicate logic, like a lot:

> ```
>     if youranswer == correctanswer:
>         print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (correctanswer, otherremaining)
>     else:
>         print "Which means it is either your answer: %r, or the only other remaining option, %r." % (youranswer, correctanswer)
> ```

I suggest simplifying these by use of different methods:

```
    answer_to_print_one = your_answer
    answer_to_print_two = correct_answer
    if your_answer == correct_answer:
        answer_to_print_one = correct_answer
        answer_to_print_two = other_remaining
    print "Which means it is either your answer: {a1}, or the only other remaining option, {a2}.".format(a1=answer_to_print_one, a2=answer_to_print_two)
```

---

### Using `"" %`:

This is an outdated and inefficient way of string concatenation:

Use `"{string}".format(string=your_string)` style concatenation.

---

### Using a `class`:

At the moment, you have a bunch of random, relational functions that pass input around, parameters etc.

Use a `class` instead, this allows you to:

- Link the functions properly
- Store parameters at a class level, reducing need for parameters
- Store multiple instances of games

Answer (score 4):

Your names are clear and that's good, but some of your names have a redundancy issue particularly from being verbose.

For example:

```
def playchosengame(chosengame):
```

You realise this is just as readable like this:

```
def play(chosengame):
```

And of course you just call it with

```
play(gamechoice)
```

If there was another function that played music, then you may need to add `play_game`, but as it stands there's little ambiguity because of how the parameters are being named. It's more important that the lines read well, rather than trying to make each name tell you everything about its value.